# Char values are empty after iteration in another function in C

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xerces, xerces-c

I'm parsing an xml using xerces c++ library & attempting storing some tags & values that I require.

I have a dynamically allocated  char array that stores actual values from the parsed XML, those values are later empty/missing?

Note: I'm using a C++ compiler, I intend to write the code as  much as possible in C.

See relevant snippets of  the main function (Note important walk_DOM() & get_data()).

```
      int main(int argc, char *args[])
 {
    //pass in as console argument 
    char *xmlFile = args[1];
    file_observational_area *_file_observational_area = NULL;
    //initialize  file_observational_area
    _file_observational_area = calloc_file_observational_area(_file_observational_area, 1);

    /*xerces irrelevant code was not included in post as xerces is working*/

    parser->parse(xmlFile);

    DOMDocument *dom = parser->getDocument();

    DOMNodeList *dom_node_list = dom->getChildNodes();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dom_node_list->getLength(); i++)
    {
        walk_DOM(dom_node_list->item(i), _file_observational_area);
    }

    get_data(_file_observational_area, xmlFile, 0, 0, 0, _field_data_values_array);

 }
```

**Header for field_delilmited type:**

```
#
ifndef FIELD_DELIMITED_H
#define FIELD_DELIMITED_H

# ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{#
    endif

    struct field_delimited
    {
        char *name;
        char *data_type;
        char *unit;
        char *description;

    };

    typedef struct field_delimited field_delimited;

    /*=============================================================================
    Function        correct_column_headers
    Description:    Are all the headers read from data from the same as described 
     *             in the XML?
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:         0 for false &1 for true    
    ==========================================================*/
    int correct_column_headers(field_delimited *_field_delimited, int expected_number_of_columns, char *delimiter, char *read_header);

    #
    ifdef __cplusplus
}#
endif

# endif /*FIELD_DELIMITED_H */
```

**See relevant snippet of parse_dom_PDS4()**, this is the function that sets the values initially in  _file_observational_area-`>_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited`, however  later the values are empty when iterated in  getData():

```
    file_observational_area* parse_dom_PDS4(DOMNode *dom_node, file_observational_area *_file_observational_area)
{
    /*<Field_Delimited>*/
    if (XMLString::equals(dom_node_name, XMLString::transcode("Field_Delimited")))
    {
        /*<Field_Delimited>
          <name>enc4</name>
          <data_type>ASCII_Real</data_type>
          <unit>rad</unit>
          <description>Joint 4 encoder counts[RA_DOF]</description>
          </Field_Delimited>*/

        /*<Field_Delimited>*/
        XMLCh *tag_Field_Delimited_name = XMLString::transcode("name");
        string tag_Field_Delimited_name_val;
        XMLCh *tag_Field_Delimited_data_type = XMLString::transcode("data_type");
        string tag_Field_Delimited_data_type_val;
        XMLCh *tag_Field_Delimited_unit = XMLString::transcode("unit");
        string tag_Field_Delimited_unit_val;
        XMLCh *tag_Field_Delimited_description = XMLString::transcode("description");
        string tag_Field_Delimited_description_val;
        DOMElement *currentElement = NULL;
        cout << "<Field_Delimited> DETECTED\n";
        int number_of_fields = _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->fields;

        _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited = malloc_field_delimited(_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited, number_of_fields);

        if (dom_node->hasChildNodes())
        {
            //            get Record_Delimited children 
            dom_node_list = dom_node->getChildNodes();

            if (NULL != dom_node_list)
            {
                /*<Field_Delimited> start loop*/
                for (unsigned int Field_Delimited_index = 0; Field_Delimited_index < number_of_fields; Field_Delimited_index++)
                {
                    if (NULL != dom_node_list->item(Field_Delimited_index))
                    {
                        currentElement = dynamic_cast<xercesc::DOMElement*> (dom_node_list->item(Field_Delimited_index));

                        if (NULL != currentElement && NULL != currentElement->getNodeName())
                        {
                            if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_name, currentElement->getNodeName()))
                            {
                                _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].name = XMLString::transcode(currentElement->getTextContent());
                                cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_name_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].name << "\n";
                            }

                            if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_data_type, currentElement->getNodeName()))
                            {
                                _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].data_type = XMLString::transcode(currentElement->getTextContent());
                                cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_data_type_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].data_type << "\n";
                            }

                            if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_unit, currentElement->getNodeName()))
                            {
                                _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].unit = XMLString::transcode(currentElement->getTextContent());
                                cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_unit_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].unit << "\n";
                            }

                            if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_description, currentElement->getNodeName()))
                            {
                                _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].description = XMLString::transcode(currentElement->getTextContent());
                                cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_description_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Field_Delimited_index].description << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }   //end item is not  empty 

                } /*<Field_Delimited> end loop */

            }   //end dom node list is not empty 

        }   //end has children 
    }   //end  /*<Field_Delimited>*/
    //other code follows but in irrelevant 
}
```

Later Im traversing `_file_observational_area` and other values are there as expected , however values in 
`_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited` are  missing/empty??

**See relevant snippet below, values are empty now**

```
 void get_data(file_observational_area *_file_observational_area, char *pds4_xml_path, int dimensions, int *start_indices, int *end_indices, field_data_value *field_data_values)
    {
        //number of  fields
        if (_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->fields > 0)
        {
            //allocate memory for actual data 
            int field_data_value_memory_size = _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->records *_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->fields;

            field_data_values = (field_data_value*) malloc(field_data_value_memory_size* sizeof(field_data_value));

            // _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited
            int row_count = 0;
            buffer_size = _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->offset;

            for (int field_record_index = 0; field_record_index < _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->fields; field_record_index++)
            {
                if (NULL != _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited)
                {
                    _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].name;
                    cout << "name :" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].name << "\n";

                    //datatype
                    _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].data_type;
                    cout << "data_type:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].data_type << "\n";
                    //unit
                    _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].unit;
                    cout << "unit:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].unit << "\n";
                    //unit
                    //description 
                    _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].description;
                    cout << "description:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].description << "\n";

                    //TODO:  check _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->field_delimiter
                    //TODO:// split character_buffer based on _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->field_delimiter
                    //TODO: output another file for testing, later data structure for querying 

                }
            }

            //other code follows but in irrelevant 

        }
```

Header for file_observational.h:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "data_file.h"
    #include "header.h"
    #include "table_delimited.h"
    #include "record_delimited.h"
    #include "field_delimited.h"
    #include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
    #include <xercesc/dom/DOMNode.hpp>

    #ifndef FILE_OBSERVATIONAL__H
    #define FILE_OBSERVATIONAL__H

        struct file_observational_area 
     {
       data_file * _file; 
       header * _header; 
       table_delimited  * _table_delimited; 

     };

    typedef struct  file_observational_area  file_observational_area; 



    /*=============================================================================
    Function        calloc_file_observational_area
    Description:    Allocates memory for file_observational_area and children
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:            
    ==========================================================*/
    file_observational_area *
    calloc_file_observational_area (file_observational_area * _file_observational_area, int MAX_SIZE);

    /*=============================================================================
    Function        destroy_file_observational_area
    Description:    free allocated memory for file_observational_area and children
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:            
    ==========================================================*/
    void
    destroy_file_observational_area (file_observational_area * _file_observational_area);

    /*=============================================================================
    Function        parse_dom_PDS4
    Description:    parse based on PDS4 tags 
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:            
    ==========================================================*/
    field_delimited * malloc_field_delimited(field_delimited * _field_delimited, int number_of_fields);


    /*=============================================================================
    Function        free_field_delimited
    Description:     free allocated memory for _record_delimited->_field_delimited
     *                  dynamic array 
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:            
    ==========================================================*/
    void
    free_field_delimited(field_delimited * _field_delimited, int number_of_fields);

    //file_observational_area * parse_dom_PDS4(DOMNode * dom_node, 
    //        file_observational_area * _file_observational_area);

    /*=============================================================================
    Function        malloc_field_delimited
    Description:     allocated memory for _record_delimited->_field_delimited
     *                  dynamic array 
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:            
    ==========================================================*/



    #endif /* FILE_OBSERVATIONAL__H */
```

**Relevant portion of the output after program is run:**

DETECTED

,tag_Field_Delimited_name_val:grapple_phase

,tag_Field_Delimited_data_type_val:ASCII_Integer

,tag_Field_Delimited_unit_val:none

,tag_Field_Delimited_description_val:grapple phase

Debug: get_data() full_file_path:/home/anaim/sample_pds4_files/for_ary/A0087_0008_597249118_597252671_181130002623_eu.csv

_file_observational_area->_header->parsing_standard_id:7-Bit ASCII Text

_file_observational_area->_header->parsing_standard_id:Column headings

TABLE

record delimited

name :

data_type:

unit:

description:

name :grapple_phase

data_type:

unit:

description:

name :

data_type:

unit:

description:

name :

data_type:ASCII_Integer

unit:

description:

name :

data_type:

unit:

description:

As you can see names are outputted initially such as `tag_Field_Delimited_name_val:Ft` however later become empty when iterating in the get_data() function. Why are text values gone??

Comment: Here are some ways to get people into a more helpful mood. Make your [mre] more minimal. Make your mre reproducable, because it cannot compile like currently shown (your linebreaks within prepro lines are enough to prevent that). Do not use identifiers which start in a `_`.  People will otherwise discuss these things before saying things you will find helpful.

Comment: Please write *either* C *or* C++, don't try to mix it. Mixing languages and idioms usually turns into unmaintainable and generally unstable code.

Comment: I understand that you might want to write C++ code in the most C-ish way, but for a question here I recommend to do either or. Otherwise that will be discussed to. (seeing above comment, .... ).

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere in your code you are saving pointers to character strings that have a limited lifetime, you'll need to copy those strings into your own arrays or a `std::string`

Comment: May I ask what's your reason to use a `C++` compiler, but write as much as `C` as possible? Do you intend to use this in a `C` or a `C++` code base? If you use it in `C++` I recommend to use `std::string` and other `C++` constructs as string handling in `C` is inferior and error-prone.

Comment: I scrolled past your entire question just to tell you there is way too much code. Keep it minimal. [mcve].